# Widlfly 20: Web.xml and standalone.xml configs for datasource

Tags: wildfly, datasource, jndi

I have a ejb-based application deployed initially in jboss AS 5.0 that i'm upgrading to wildfly 20, the problem is that i cant resolve correctly the datasources defined in web.xml in the datasource section in standalone.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>Midd2</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <mapped-name>jdbc/SybaseDB</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>Midd</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <mapped-name>jdbc/SybaseDS2</mapped-name>
 </resource-ref>
```

My datasources in standalone.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/SybaseDB" pool-name="SybaseDB">   
    <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX/database</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver</driver-class>    
    <driver>
        jconn3.jar
    </driver>       
    <security>
        <user-name>x</user-name>
        <password>y</password>
    </security>
      <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
      </pool>
</datasource>

<datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/SybaseDS2" pool-name="SybaseDS2">   
    <connection-url>jdbc:sybase:XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX/database</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver</driver-class>
    
    <driver>
        jconn3.jar
    </driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>x</user-name>
        <password>y</password>
    </security>

    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
</datasource>
```

But i'm getting

```
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.naming.context.java.module.Midd.Midd.env.Midd2 is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.Midd.Midd.env.jdbc.SybaseDB]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.module.Midd.Midd.env.Midd is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.Midd.Midd.env.jdbc.SybaseDS2]"
]
```

I've read a lot of docs in google but nothing that could help

Comment: Did you deploy the driver JAR or did you install it as a module?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the annotation to inject the data source?

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/SybaseDB")
private DataSource dataSource1;
    
@Resource(name = "jdbc/SybaseDS2")
private DataSource dataSource2;
```

Where do you put the jconn3.jar?